# Is it safe leaving monitors turned on (stand by) or could it harm the devices

Tags: display, lcd, led

I was wondering if I could leave my monitors turned on after I’ve turned off my PC, here are some other questions I had:

Does the yellow status LED always suggest the monitor is in standby mode? Every time I turn on the monitor without turning in my computer the light is yellow instead of green or blue respectively. Does that mean it automatically turns into stand by?

I have one 144hz BenQ led lcd monitor which lights up green in use and yellow when my PC is turned off and an old LG lcd with a mercury containing CCFL tube which usually lights up blue I think and if my PC is turned off yellow, not sure If that’s important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal. The Monitor operates normally upon operating the PC device itself. Usually LEDs have a living time of 5 years before starting to mis-operate and die !!!

Comment: Though LEDs are generally rated to last 50,000 hours (5.7 years), I have never had an issue with a LED power light on a monitor going out. I guess I'll see if one of mine goes out within the year. I've had it for 5 years and the light is always on. I've had my other monitor for 8 years and it's still going too. But that power LED flashes every few seconds when it's on standby.

Comment: remember that the lifetime is for a full duty cycle - or operating at 100%.  If an LED is running at a lower voltage or is pulse width modulated to a less intense output - it's going to last longer.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to leave them on. I always leave mine on and doing so has caused no harm.

The different colors are used to help troubleshoot problems, if something occurs. The one color shows it has power, but is not receiving video input. The other is when it is powered on and receiving input.

When the power is supplied to the monitor, and it is on but not receiving video input, the status light will be one color or flashing pattern. In your case, these colors seem to be a solid orange and yellow.

When you turn on your PC, or wake it, your monitor will receive video input and the LED will turn a different color, or stop flashing. In your case this seems to be green and blue.

The LED color or flashing pattern is unique to each monitor. I have one that has a flashing red when in standby mode, and a solid red light when it receives video input. My other monitor has an orange LED when in standby, and a blue light when it is receiving input.